rails submission does not generate pop-up dialog
The following HTML:
<form data-turbo="false" data-turbo-confirm="Are you sure?" action="/mergeables/cancel" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="[..]" autocomplete="off">
        <input value="8" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Cancel merge" data-disable-with="Cancel merge">
</form>

is generated by:
<%= form_with(url: cancel_mergeables_path, data: { turbo: false, turbo_confirm: t('mergeable.cancel_confirm') } ) do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :id, value: mergeable.id %>
  <%= form.submit t('user.merge_cancel').capitalize %>
<% end %>

I suspect there is a conflict between the turbo and turbo_confirm attributes. The dialog appears if turbo: false, is removed.
Then, how does one go about processing this form as HTML and still maintain a dialog box for comfirming said action?

I guess data-turbo: false disables turbo for this Dom Node, rather than for the submission only. The user answer advising JS separately from Turbo seems valid.

Actually, not.  The rails magic creates this opacity.   Removing turbo: false, allows the dialog to appears, but then in the controller action, the processing of TURBO_STREAM can be over-ridden by forcing an HTML rendering. For the above use-case re-directing did do the trick.  The Rails way has its raison d'être...

TURBO_STREAM doesn't change the regular form workflow, you can redirect or render an html response as usual. it's only when you add a turbo_stream format things change. you can add <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :html %> into your form, to force an html response over turbo_stream (if you have both).

data-turbo="false" disables all features provided by Turbo. Including the confirmation handler which is baked into how it handles form submissions. There really is no straight forward way to just opt out of parts of it.
That said the functionality provided by Turbo is hardly rocket science - it's just an event handler that fires the native confirm function used by the browser with a few extra steps added. You can easily create such a generic event handler in a few minutes or use any of the gazillion libraries that provide a "better" version of the native confirm dialog.


document.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  if (!event.target.matches('[data-xconfirm]')) return;
  if (confirm(event.target.dataset['xconfirm'])) {
    return; // exits and does the default event
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}); 
<form data-xconfirm="RU Sure mate?">
  <button>Click me</button>
</form>




This uses standard HTML/JavaScript confirmation and works with Turbo disabled.
   <%= form_with(url: cancel_mergeables_path, 
                  data: { turbo: false }, 
                  html: { onsubmit: "return confirm('#{t('mergeable.cancel_confirm')}')" }) do |form| %>


vastly prefer a non JavaScript solution, for testing purposes.
